# Export a Bean from one JMX server to another JMX server

Tags: java, jmx

Is it possible to get an already registered MBean from one JMX server to another?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: You can use a JMX client in one JVM to talk to another JMX server.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this by spinning up your own MBean proxies and remotely registering them, but the easier way to do this is to use [MBean Server Federation](https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/federating_mbeanservers_with_opendmk) (also referred to as cascading). The [OpenDMK](http://opendmk.java.net/) library has classes which make this fairly straight forward. Or if you are maven inclined, there's a [mavenized fork](https://github.com/nickman/OpenDMK).